# Why is calling CssClass returning NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to retrieve the css class of an `<input>` field in my code-behind, however both of the following calls are returning NULL even though the page's element clearly has a class in the markup.

```
if (d.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
{
   TextBox txtComments = (TextBox)d;
   string className = txtComments.CssClass; //NULL
   string className2 = txtComments.Attributes["class"]; //NULL
   string id = txtComments.ID; //Does work correctly
   string commentText = txtComments.Text; //Does work correctly
}
```

The markup is straight forward and clearly shows a class when i inspect it in Chrome.

```
<input name="rptReviewTask$ctl00$rptReviewTaskDetails$ctl01$2" type="text" value="com 2" id="rptReviewTask_rptReviewTaskDetails_0_2_1" placeholder="Comments" class="4" style="width:100%">
```

The element id dyanmically added to the page here:

```
TextBox txtComments = new TextBox();
txtComments.ID = ReviewTaskId.ToString();
txtComments.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "Comments");
txtComments.Attributes.Add("style", "width:100%");
txtComments.Attributes.Add("class", "4");
txtComments.Text = comments;
divTask.Controls.Add(txtComments);
```

Comment: What happens if, instead of `txtComments.Attributes.Add("class", "4");` you do `txtComments.CssClass = "4";`?  Perhaps the framework just isn't tracking changes manually made to client-side attributes.  Where does `d` come from in the first place?  HTML markup isn't posted to the server, so that information might simply not be there.

Comment: @David Well that would a problem if that is the case.  What i actually need to do is dynamically change some sort of property(class,name,id; something!) on the client side and read that new property value once submitted.

Comment: Then that *definitely* won't work, because HTML markup is never posted to the server.  If you want to send a value from the client to the server, you're looking for form elements.  Things like `<input>` elements, for example.

Comment: @David This is an input element, but you're saying the server can only read the changed values of the actual "value" of the `<input>`

Comment: I'm saying that the server can only read the information it's given.  In your browser's debugging tools take a look at the actual data being sent to the server.  It doesn't include the *entire HTML* of the page.  Input values are how forms post data to the server.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll find another way.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup use the `Hidden` control, populate that with your value, that will be posted back.

Comment: @mxmissile Yes, thats what i'm going to do. It's just a matter of getting that control instance.  I have to loop through multiple parent controls and repeaters to find it.  I'll figure it out.